# what will be the value of $x$ and $y$ and why?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Compute the area of that portion of the conical surface $x^2+y^2=z^2$ which lies above the $xy-plane$ and is cut off by the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=2ax$.

**My attempt** : According to given question , we can take

$$r(u, \theta) = u\cos \theta \hat{i} + u\sin\theta \hat{j} + u\hat{k}$$

$$r_u = \cos\theta\hat{i} + \sin\theta\hat{j} + \hat{k}$$
$$r_\theta = -u\sin\theta\hat{i} + u\cos\theta\hat{j}$$

Therefore $$\|r_u\times r_\theta\| = \sqrt2u$$

It is given in question that  area cutoff by the sphere, so we have
$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 2ax$$
$$\implies 2z^2 \leq 2ax $$
$$\implies u \leq a\cos\theta$$

$$Area = \int \int_{S} dS=\int_{x}^{y} \int_{0}^{acos \theta } \sqrt 2 u du d \theta$$

**My confusion** : How to find   the  $x$ and $y$ in Area.

Im finding difficulty  in choosing the  $x$ and $ y$ .  what will be the value of  $x$ and $y$ and why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of the sphere can be re-written as $(x-a)^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2$.

It is a sphere centered at $(a, 0, 0)$, with radius $a$.

In $XY$ plane (at $z = 0$), you get the circle with the equation,

$x^2 + y^2 = 2 a x \implies r = 2a \cos \theta$. Hence, $-\frac{\pi}{2} \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.

So your integral to find surface area should be,

$\displaystyle \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{a \cos \theta } \sqrt2 \ u \ du \ d\theta$

Edit: Added a diagram as requested that explains limits of $\theta$ for the circle, with center on $x$-axis and touching the origin.

[image]

Comment: oks thanks u @Math lover u mean           $ r  =0        $ , $0= acos \theta  ? $

Comment: Yes the circle $r = 2 a \cos \theta$ will form between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$. You plug in $\theta = 0$ and you can see $r = 2a$ and similarly it starts at $-\pi/2$ ($r = 0)$ and the circle completes at $\pi/2$. Angle being measured is from the origin. Let me know if it is clear or should I add a diagram?

Comment: ya  it will be better ..if u add the diagram , because the i want to see the diagram @Math lover

Comment: I just added a diagram. See if it helps.

Comment: ..@Math lover thanks a lots for this diagram,,,Now      my doubts is cleared

Comment: You are welcome!